# Merge sort in python without slicing using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Here is my solution to a merge sort in python.

My notes:

1. The time is 2n(log(n)) instead of n(log(n)) because of the stack in recursion. I can't see any way to fix this.
2. A bottom up recursion method is actually easier and is n(log(n))
3. I have seen my solution that use slicing. For example:

   lefthalf = alist[:mid]
   righthalf = alist[mid:]
   mergeSort(lefthalf)
   mergeSort(righthalf)

However, these solutions ignore that a slice takes k time, because a slice takes k times. So the above code actually is:

```
lefthalf = []

for i in range(mid): #k times
    lefhalf.append(alist[i])
for i in range(mid, len(alist): #k times
    righthalf.append(alist[i])
```

My solution:

```
import random
def _merge_sort(indices, the_list):
    start = indices[0]
    end = indices[1]
    half_way = (end - start)//2 + start
    if start < half_way:
        _merge_sort((start, half_way), the_list)
    if half_way + 1 <= end and end - start != 1:
       _merge_sort((half_way + 1, end), the_list)
    #a stack is created using log(n) number of recursions
    sort_sub_list(the_list, indices[0], indices[1])


def sort_sub_list(the_list, start, end):
    orig_start = start
    initial_start_second_list = (end - start)//2 + start + 1
    list2_first_index = initial_start_second_list
    new_list = []
    while start < initial_start_second_list and list2_first_index <= end:
        first1 = the_list[start]
        first2 = the_list[list2_first_index]
        if first1 > first2:
            new_list.append(first2)
            list2_first_index += 1
        else:
            new_list.append(first1)
            start += 1
    while start < initial_start_second_list:
        new_list.append(the_list[start])
        start += 1

    while list2_first_index <= end:
        new_list.append(the_list[list2_first_index])
        list2_first_index += 1
    # at this point, the total number each while statement ran is  n
    # now we have to do n again!
    for i in new_list:
        the_list[orig_start] = i
        orig_start += 1


def merge_sort(the_list):
    return _merge_sort((0, len(the_list) - 1), the_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(100):
        n = 100
        l = range(n)
        random.shuffle(l)
        merge_sort(l)
        assert l == range(n)
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Is this a code review or did you have a problem?

Comment: I guess my question would be how to make this run in n(log(n)) time.

Comment: `2nlog(n)` is same as `nlog(n)`. Constants are ignored when dealing in big O notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant

Comment: If you need slices without creating new objects you can take a look at memoryview.

Comment: Actually memory view is useful if you want to write something into array slice. Until you try to write something into a common slice there is no any object copies.